Run an alteryx gallery workflow using alteryx API
I am new to alteryx and I am trying to access Alteryx Gallery API from power automate or in postman.
For Example, I am using get /v3/workflows/{workflowId}
I have API key and Secret, I am trying to do get or post but getting 401 error in both power automate and postman.
Is it possible to access Alteryx Gallery API from power automate?
